# Unknown Eclipse Errors using gfortran, Cygwin

Tags: eclipse, cygwin, fortran, gfortran

Using Windows 7 64 bit.  I've followed [these instructions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GfCmiEbGtpE) for installing Eclipse for Parallel Application Developers and Cygwin, the latter because I want `gfortran` to compile Fortran code.  At 18:20 in the linked tutorial he compiles in Eclipse with no errors, but I get the following 2 errors (Project is called "example"):

```
Description                          Resource     Path            Location   Type
make: *** [example] Error 1          example                                 C/C++ Problem
recipe for target 'example' failed   makefile     /example/Debug  line 29    C/C++ Problem
```

My code (main.f90, under project "example") is simply

```
program main
    print*, "hello world"
end program main
```

I've also tried compiling through the terminal, but get the following:

```
>>gfortran main.f90
gfortran: fatal error: -fuse-linker-plugin, but cyglto_plugin.dll not found
compilation terminated
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You know that `gfortran` works in Windows, too?!

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial, you linked, is 2 years old...

As far as I see from the content of the packages available from http://www.cygwin.com/packages/, you have to install `gcc-fortran` instead of `gcc4-fortran`, because the latter one is labeled as obsolete.

The library `cyglto_plugin.dll`, which is used for Link-Time-Optimization, can be found in the package `gcc-core` and should be installed as a dependency. You could try to disable this library by using `-fno-use-linker-plugin`, but this will disable some optimization.

Comment: OK, I just checked the Cygwin setup and apparently `gcc-core: GNU Compiler Collection (C, OpenMP)` was already installed (this is the only `gcc-core` I found in the package list).  I also installed `gcc-fortran` since it was the only `fortran` compiler shown as available.